# Double nested UI layout causing StackOverflow on null call()

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My app uses a hierachy of UI designs and extended designs for the correct layout (naturally).

One of my hierachies is a simple 3 layer approach:

```
HomePage (content) -> 
                       UiBaseMain (structure for content) -> 
                                                             UiBase (scaffolding)
```

---

**Details:** (and an MVCE) - I have tried narrowing down to the simplest form to get repeatedly throw this error.

*Tested on both physical devices and AVD, both give a Stack Overflow error.*

**UiBase (ui_component_base.dart)** (which all layouts are based on)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class UiBase extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget widget;

  const UiBase({Key key, this.widget})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: widget),
    );
  }
}
```

**UiBaseMain (ui_main_navbar_appbar.dart)** (where all Main UI content is shown with i.e. Dashboard, settings, etc which ideally alsop contains a small logo ontop, a BottomNavigationBar, etc)

```
import 'package:mytestapp/ui/design/ui_component_base.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class UiBaseMain extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget widget;

  const UiBaseMain({Key key, this.widget}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UiBaseMain createState() => _UiBaseMain();
}

class _UiBaseMain extends State<UiBaseMain> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return UiBase(
      widget: widget,
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, **HomePage (ui_homepage.dart)** (which is a content page, should show user content, etc)

```
import 'package:mytestapp/ui/design/ui_main_navbar_appbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UiBaseMain(
      widget: Text("test"),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Problem**

Using the above structure, I consistently get the following Stack Overflow error

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building Material(type: canvas, color: Color(0xfffafafa), dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#1c4c4], _EffectiveTickerMode], state: _MaterialState#b2ccd):
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/CybeX/mytestapp/mytestapp-mobile-flutter/lib/ui/design/ui_component_base.dart:14:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _WordWrapParseMode.values (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:776:6)
#1      _SyncIterator.moveNext (dart:core-patch/core_patch.dart:165:25)
#2      Iterable.length (dart:core/iterable.dart:429:15)
#3      _PrefixedStringBuilder._finalizeLine (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:856:30)
#4      _PrefixedStringBuilder.write (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:973:9)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/CybeX/mytestapp/mytestapp-mobile-flutter/lib/ui/design/ui_component_base.dart:14:12
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/CybeX/mytestapp/mytestapp-mobile-flutter/lib/ui/design/ui_component_base.dart:14:12
====================================================================================================
```

---

**Question**

Is this an issue my side or is this an issue others can confirm and infact a bug in the Flutter framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass here `widget.widget` because it is a stateful widget, no? : return UiBase(
widget: widget,
);
Sorry not convenient to write from phone.